# Perl PDF::API2 and unicode

Tags: perl, pdf, unicode

I am trying to write a unicode string to a PDF::API2 object, but I does not work, I get unicode characters messed up

```
our $pageWidth = 1.25*595;
our $pageHeight = 1.25*842;

my $titleSize = 16;

my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();
$pdf->mediabox((0, 0, $pageWidth, $pageHeight));

my $font = $pdf->corefont('Times', -encode => 'utf-8');

my $page = $pdf->page();
my $text = $page->gfx();

$text->font($font, $titleSize);

my $title = '(Nėra pavadinimo šiam puslapiui)';
my $titleWidth = $text->advancewidth($title);

$text->translate(($pageWidth - $titleWidth) / 2, $pageHeight - $titleSize * 2);
$text->text($title);
my $pdfString = $pdf->stringify();
```

I get `(N ra pavadinimo �iam puslapiui)`. 
What I am doing wrong

Comment: did you specify `use utf8;` in your script and did you save it in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes made both of the thing you mentioned

Comment: Did you check the PDF specification to see if the characters "ė" and "š" are available in the core (built-in) font "Times"?

Comment: Ah well, yes none of the fonts have the symbols I need registered. I think I need to figure out how tu use unifont() for registering fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out by using the following [source](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=954373)